# Integrating Jawr with a CDN (CloudFront)

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront, jawr

We're making use of Jawr to bundle javascript and css for a largescale Spring project.  One of our requirements is to serve all assets (js, images, css etc) via a CDN (CloudFront).

So far, we've externalised the Jawr working directory to a central S3 bucket and have mapped CloudFront over to top to serve files from this bucket on a sub domain.  We now need to tell Jawr to make use of the CDN rather than the Spring controller (and include the cache busting hash).

Has anyone had any experience with this type of configuration?  There seems to be a total lack of documentation for Jawr in general and specifically around integrating Jawr with a CDN.

Thanks in advance.